# Difficulty with py2neo, neo4j and AJAX

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to set up a webpage that a user can enter in a node number and have my external python code query neo4j then post the results of that query back to the webpage.

relevant html code where I'm trying to use AJAX:

```
<h4>Enter Node Name for Search</h4>                     
<input id="numb" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x, text;
    x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    if (isNaN(x)) {                             
        text = "Input not valid";
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "python/neo.py",
            dataType:"html",
            data: {param: x},                               
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $(data).text().trim();},
            error: doError,
            });
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
</script>
```

Here is the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division
import sys
from py2neo import neo4j,node, rel, cypher

url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/"

def node_info(a):

try:
    graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService(url)
    query = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db, 
    """CYPHER 2.0
        MATCH (n)-[r*..2]-(m)
        WHERE id(n)={z}
        RETURN labels(n), count(m) AS connected_count, collect (id(m)) as connected_nodes
        """) 
    result = query.execute(z=a)
    for r in result:                       
        print r.values

except Exception as e:
    print e

if __name__ == '__main__':

    startnode=int(sys.argv[1])
    node_info(startnode)
```

I want `r.values` from the python code printed to the webpage in the `success:` block, unless I'm misunderstanding how the success block works.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into python web programming? And also check for converting py2neo results into JSON that then would be received and consumed by your webpage.

Comment: this is the equivalent of asking if I've googled my issue.

Comment: User, you're just printing text in your python app.  Web apps don't work that way - you need to return an HTTP response

Comment: Michael's comment on looking into web programming is perfectly valid, as is Frobber's. Your in-browser JavaScript is making an XHR request to a Python file that prints its output to stdout instead of serving it as a web response. You need to gain a deeper understanding of the mechanics of HTTP and XHR (AJAX) and this is something that Google is far better to help you with than StackOverflow is.